# MVC # URI fragment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

So I'm working on using the Facebook API and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to access the URI fragment from a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/MyController/MyAction#access_token=LONGTOKENSTRINGHERE&expires_in=6355
```

I need the values after the "#".  The only options available underneath Request return every before the "#".  I would use client-side JS, but I need the Server to get the values for the Access Token as well as the Expires time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: There's an option within the facebook application configuration to have it use the query string instead of hash.

Comment: That option seems to make more sense.  Using a page anchor for a token seems like a misuse of the anchor.

Comment: I realize that as well, but the "code" option requires one more server side step, that I was going to be lazy and avoid.  But it looks like I'll have to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors (designated with `#`) do not get sent to the server at all... they are resolved locally (i.e. client-side) by the browser... javascript can access this via `window.location.hash`.

IF you need these server-side you either find a way to tell facebook to use the query string instead of an anchor OR you use some javascript to access that information and send it along with the request...